# How to create an animation inside AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-alertdialog

I want to create a custom AlertDialog or DialogBox with animated circle inside it.Here is an example of functionality which I want from Google Chrome browser for Android:
[image]

So how can I implement this?

Comment: That's just a [Progressbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html). You can create a ProgressDialog with custom background